# restrict users with ldap in airflow

Tags: ldap, airflow, memberof

I've gotten ldap authentication to work within airflow, but it's allowing any user we have in our directory to login. While it's only showing admin privs for members of the airflow-admin AD group, i would expect users that aren't a member of airflow-admin or airflow-profiler groups to be denied access and this isn't the case. 
Here's my config:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth

[ldap]
uri = ldaps://ldaps.mydomain.com:636
user_filter = objectClass=person
user_name_attr = sAMAccountName
group_member_attr = memberOf
superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-admin,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com
data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-profiler,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com
bind_user = cn=ldapadmin,ou=Admins,dc=mydomain,dc=com
bind_password = ******
basedn = dc=mydomain,dc=com
cacert = /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mydomain.crt
search_scope = SUBTREE
```

I see several other similar posts with no resolution, i'm beginning to wonder if this even works. 
Here's a link to the airflow doc section on ldap. 
https://airflow.apache.org/security.html?#ldap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to filter them out via the user_filter?

The following should only allow users in one of the two mentioned groups access.  Unfortunately I do not have Airflow to test and verify this.

```
user_filter = |(memberOf=CN=airflow-admin,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=airflow-profiler,OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com)
```

Comment: that caused the following error:


File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/operation/search.py", line 215, in parse_filter
    raise LDAPInvalidFilterError('malformed filter')
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidFilterError: malformed filter

Comment: that appears to be working! thanks!   You would think they would clarify that in their docs...